# Typescript async function return type void or other value

Tags: typescript, express, model-view-controller, middleware

I'm new to typescript and I'm working on a typescript / express backend REST API, on an MVC architecture.

I'm often stuck on some helper functions that I try to create, which can return next(new AppError()) (type void detected by typescript) or an actual value if everything goes fine.

Here is an example of a helper function that verify if country and city exists in my DB :

```
import { IVerifiedCity } from "../interfaces/controllers/verifiedCityInterface";
import { NextFunction } from "express";
import AppError from "../utils/errors/appError";
import { HttpCodes } from "../utils/errors/httpStatusCode";

export const verifyCityInDb = async (
    next: NextFunction,
    countryName: string,
    cityName: string,
    zipCodeValue: string
): Promise<void | IVerifiedCity> => {
    if (
        zipCodeValue === undefined ||
        zipCodeValue === "" ||
        cityName === undefined ||
        cityName === "" ||
        countryName === undefined ||
        countryName === ""
    ) {
        // if someting went bad, return next with custom AppError that extends Error class
        return next(
            new AppError(
                "Les informations du code postale, de la ville et du pays n'ont pas permis de trouver une localisation valide dans notre base de données.",
                HttpCodes.NOT_FOUND
            )
        );
    } else {
        // ... some async logic here that search in DB if items exists

        return {
            verifiedCountry: countryInDb,
            verifiedZipCode: formattedZipCode,
            verifiedCity: cityInDb,
        };
    }
};
```

In this situation, I return an error of type void or an actual object with values of type IVerifiedCity that I declared elsewhere like this:

```
import { ICityFromDb } from "../models/city/cityFromDbInterface";
import { ICountryFromDb } from "../models/country/countryFromDbInterface";

export interface IVerifiedCity {
    verifiedCountry: ICountryFromDb;
    verifiedZipCode: string;
    verifiedCity: ICityFromDb;
}
```

The error I get is on the return type, I don't know how to write it.
Actually, the value `

```
Promise<void | IVerifiedCity>
```

returns this error in my IDE : **void is only valid as a return type or generic type variable.**

Any idea how to solve that ?
Thanks in advance

I tried several return type like `Promise<void | IVerifiedCity>`
But I can't find the correct return type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you are not returning `void` you are returning `NextFunction`

you should set the return type like this `Promise<NextFunction | IVerifiedCity>`

```
export const verifyCityInDb = async (
    next: NextFunction,
    countryName: string,
    cityName: string,
    zipCodeValue: string
): Promise<NextFunction | IVerifiedCity> => {
    if (
        zipCodeValue === undefined ||
        zipCodeValue === "" ||
        cityName === undefined ||
        cityName === "" ||
        countryName === undefined ||
        countryName === ""
    ) {
        // if someting went bad, return next with custom AppError that extends Error class
        return next(
            new AppError(
                "Les informations du code postale, de la ville et du pays n'ont pas permis de trouver une localisation valide dans notre base de données.",
                HttpCodes.NOT_FOUND
            )
        );
    } else {
        // ... some async logic here that search in DB if items exists

        return {
            verifiedCountry: countryInDb,
            verifiedZipCode: formattedZipCode,
            verifiedCity: cityInDb,
        };
    }
};
```

or this would be another method

```
    export const verifyCityInDb = async (
        next: NextFunction,
        countryName: string,
        cityName: string,
        zipCodeValue: string
    ): Promise<undefined| IVerifiedCity> => {
        if (
            zipCodeValue === undefined ||
            zipCodeValue === "" ||
            cityName === undefined ||
            cityName === "" ||
            countryName === undefined ||
            countryName === ""
        ) {
            // if someting went bad, return next with custom AppError that extends Error class
            next(
                new AppError(
                    "Les informations du code postale, de la ville et du pays n'ont pas permis de trouver une localisation valide dans notre base de données.",
                    HttpCodes.NOT_FOUND
                )

            );
        return;
        } else {
            // ... some async logic here that search in DB if items exists
    
            return {
                verifiedCountry: countryInDb,
                verifiedZipCode: formattedZipCode,
                verifiedCity: cityInDb,
            };
        }
    };

///
let verify=verifyCityInDb();
if(verify){
 /// verify success
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Your proposition with Promise<NextFunction | IVerifiedCity> was still highlighted by my IDE because I was returning void, and not a NextFunction (despite I am returning next, I don't know why it's like that...)
But your other solution with undefined seems to work ! :)
Thanks a lot !